# Multiple simultaneous Node.js data requests occasionally resulting in "aborted" error (Express, React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a web application using a front end of React and a backend of Node.js (connecting to a MS SQL database.)

In the application, on each page load, the frontend sends a few requests (via Axios) to the API backend on the server. Most of the time (95%) they all process flawlessly, but maybe 5% of the time, it results in an "Aborted" message and the application server returns a 500 error. Sometimes these requests are very small amounts of data (like a count query with only a few numbers returned, much less than 1KB - so size isn't the problem).

It seems that somehow the browser is telling the server "oh, actually I need this" and the server cancels it's previous results and works on the next request. But most of the time they all get returned.

**Here's a sample of the React context:**

```
import React, { useCallback, createContext } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack'

export const PlanContext = createContext()

export default function PlanProvider(props) {
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()
    const [sampleData, setSampleData] = useState([])

    const sampleRequest = useCallback(
        async (dateInput) => { 
          try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/sample`, {
              params: { dateInput: dateInput, },
            })
            setSampleData(data)
          } catch (error) {
            enqueueSnackbar(`Error: ${error.message}`, { variant: 'error' })
          }
        }, [enqueueSnackbar])    

      return (
        <Plan.Provider
          value={{
            sampleRequest,
            sampleData,
          }}
        >
          {props.children}
        </Plan.Provider>
      )
    }
```

**And here's a sample of the Node.JS Controller:**

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = require('../config/db')

async function sampleRequest(req, res) {
    const { dateInput } = req.query
    let pool
    try {
      pool = await sql.connect(config)
      const {recordset} = await pool.request()
      .input('dateInput', sql.Date, dateInput).query`
      SELECT * FROM DATATABLE WHERE StatusDate = @dateInput
      `
      res.json(recordset)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR: ', error.message, new Date())
      res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
    } finally {
      if (pool) {
        try {
          await pool.close()
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Error closing connection: ",err);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  module.exports = {
    sampleRequest
  }
```

And there's multiple contexts and multiple controllers pulling various pieces of data.

And here's an example of the error logged on the Node.JS server:
[image: Error]

And in the Browser console (Chrome Developer Tools):

[image: Browser]

Is there something I have mixed up with the async / await setup? I can usually re-create the error after a bit by continually refreshing the page (F5).

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the answer , I had a similar problem and I believe it is because you are opening and closing the connection pool on every request or call of your function. Instantiate the connection pool outside of the function then call pool.request(). Common practice I've seen is to have the connection pool in your db file and export the pool object and then require it in your routes.